# How do I write a new parameter into firebase database using functions at different db hierarchies?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Summary: Need a way to search the firebase database and append the matched object with a new element.
Firebase database structure is this:

```
{
  "Message2" : {
    "-KnSKLk3dhRf8MgjZAnO" : {
      "var1" : "value1",
      "var2" : "value2",
      "endDate1" : "Click to enter",
      "searchvar" : "Uhrts",
      "name" : "name",
      "numbervar" : "5",
      "startDate1" : "Click to enter",
      "varName" : "Neptune"
    },
    "-KnSKLvtA3X3NsoErfa-" : {
      "var1" : "value2",
      "var2" : "value3",
      "endDate1" : "Click to enter",
      "searchvar" : "qwe",
      "name" : "name",
      "numbervar" : "5",
      "startDate1" : "Click to enter",
      "varName" : "Neptune"
    }
  }
}
```

End goal is to search the string(say "Uhrts") in each element of root node(Messages2), and if string is present, append a new parameter to all childs of Messages2 which matches the Uhrts search(to say -KnSKLk3dhRf8MgjZAnO, ... etc).

This is the index.js code I am deploying in firebase:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.qwerty = functions.database.ref('/Messages2').onWrite(event => {
    const message = event.data.val();
    if (message) {
        var string = new RegExp("Uhrts");
        var upper;
        var lower;
        for (upper in message){
            for (lower in message[upper]){
                if (string.test(message[upper][lower])) {
                    message[upper].cost = "1500000";
                    return event.data.adminRef.update({
                    }); 
                } 
            }     
        }
    }
});
```

1. When I try to dump the data under -KnSKLk3dhRf8MgjZAnO into console, it has "cost" correctly updated for it, but the database itself is not updated and remains unchanged. What am I missing?
2. Also, I want this to happen to all child elements which have Uhrts, but the console only prints out the first match it finds. Does the 2 for loops not take care of traversing all the elements if the ref is for Messages2? How do I append to ALL the elements of the database structure instead of only one?

I am OK with changing the database structure or the code as long as the end goal described here is met.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Added the json as text. Also put a summary at the start here in case it helps. 

@Frank van Puffelen, since you are from the firebase team, if stack is not the best place for this question, any place else I can try to get a response? I have already put a feature request in the firebase bug and feature request page. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Your current function will be triggered whenever any data is written under `/Messages2`. So whenever a new node is added under here, you reprocess all existing data. Is that really your intention?

Comment: A Database-triggered function should return a single promise, which resolves when its work is done. Your current code returns potentially multiple promises. I recommend reading up on this in [this Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), [this Firecast video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc), and [this Firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/keep-your-promises-when-using-cloud.html).